# Dynamic time delay depending on time of completion of another task

Tags: python, delay

```
import time

while(1):
    # Task A
    time.delay(1)
    print('Hi')
```

In the above example code, I want to print 'Hi' every 1 sec, while simultaneously performing Task A. Task A takes a variable amount of time to complete in each iteration, but the time is well within 1 sec. I need to dynamically fix the time delay so that consecutive print statements are executed exactly 1 sec apart. What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Why do you care about how long the task is executed? Simply add `time.sleep(1)` at the end of the code block within the while loop. Also, this is not how comments are written in Python, you need to use # instead.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use `asyncio`.

If you'r task doesn't block the loop for a relative long time you can run both tasks concurrently:

```
import asyncio

async def task2():
    for i in range(7):
        print(f'Task1... {i+1}/7')
        await asyncio.sleep(1) #Use this method to sleep instead time.sleep()

async def MainTask():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'MainTask... {i+1}/5')
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
    
async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(MainTask(), task2())

asyncio.run(main())

##### OUTPUT #####
# MainTask... 1/5
# Task1... 1/7
# MainTask... 2/5
# Task1... 2/7
# MainTask... 3/5
# Task1... 3/7
# MainTask... 4/5
# Task1... 4/7
# MainTask... 5/5
# Task1... 5/7
# Task1... 6/7
# Task1... 7/7
```

If your task blocks the event loop (such as file operations):

```
async def task2():
    for i in range(7):
        print(f'Task1... {i+1}/7')
        await asyncio.sleep(1) #Use this method to sleep instead time.sleep()

def MainTask():
    for i in range(5):
        print(f'MainTask... {i+1}/5')
        time.sleep(1) 
        # Note that time.sleep() will freeze the thread for 1 sec
        # But this func will be in another thread
    
async def main():
    # wait for the both task to get done
    await asyncio.gather(
        asyncio.to_thread(MainTask), # Main task is sent to other thread
        task2())

asyncio.run(main())


##### OUTPUT #####
# MainTask... 1/5
# Task1... 1/7
# MainTask... 2/5
# Task1... 2/7
# MainTask... 3/5
# Task1... 3/7
# MainTask... 4/5
# Task1... 4/7
# MainTask... 5/5
# Task1... 5/7
# Task1... 6/7
# Task1... 7/7
```

Comment: Would the tasks be any slower since they are running concurrently with other tasks?

Comment: When a task reaches an "await" statement, it pauses and another task start to run. Think of it as "turn". Every time the "await" expression is executed, the current task yields the turn to another one, and when this other one reaches an "await" it yields to another task and so on cyclically. In other words, when a task is waiting, instead of do nothing it runs another task so don't waste time. Answering your question if some task takes too much time before reaches an "await" yes, it will be slower. To avoid this use the function "asyncio.to_thread" when you have to run a long-term task.

Comment: For example if you have 2 task, one prints a msg every second, and the other one will print a msg avery 2 seconds, it wont be slower because while one task is waiting, the other runs and so on.